# SSL certificate works on subdomain but not main domain using cloudflare and certbot

Tags: ssl, nginx, certbot

so I manage the domain britoanderson.com and I am trying to get ssl to work on it.
I used certbot to make the certificate for both www. subdomain and the main britoanderson.com domain.
I set up cloudflare to "Full" encryption mode.
For some reason, the SSL certificate works on https://www.britoanderson.com/ but not on https://britoanderson.com/ where the website just refuses to open.

Here is my nginx default file:

```
server {
    if ($host = www.britoanderson.com) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = britoanderson.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name britoanderson.com www.britoanderson.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;


        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/britoanderson.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/britoanderson.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name britoanderson.com www.britoanderson.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

Both A records for the main domain britoanderson.com and the subdomain www have been set on cloudflare.

What am I doing wrong? Why does the main website just refuse to open?

Comment: Does not refuse to open for me.

Comment: I keep getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT every time I try to access https://britoanderson.com/ , the www subdomain does work though. I even tried accessing it from different devices, same result

Answer (score 0):

Do you have restarted nginx after issuing the certificates? I can only access the http site, but not the https-site, so it looks like your https-forwarding which was done by certbot isn't working yet too.

Comment: I was messing around with the website constantly in the past 5 hours or so, perhaps I changed something that broke that but now it seems to work after removing the redirects

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my PC was giving me a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN while the actual error was within the redirects. Removing the

```
if ($host = www.britoanderson.com) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = britoanderson.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

fixed the issue